# Issue On Accessing to In Script JSON object in jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Can you please take a look at [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/u0b0djzy/) and let me know how to access to JSON object like `credit` which is declared inside the same requester script as:

```
var credit = [{
    "name": "John Johnson",
    "street": "Oslo West 16",
    "phone": "222 7894562"
}, {
    "name": "Davie Amber",
    "street": "Alberta 52",
    "phone": "555 1234567"
}, {
    "name": "Marck William",
    "street": "Delestre 125",
    "phone": "666 7254599"
}];

$("button").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "credit",
        success: function (result) {
            $("#div1").html(result);
        }
    });
});
```

I know in real world, there is no need to do this since is doable in simple JavaScript but for doing a specific test I need to provide the test environment like this which is running by `$.ajax()` method.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mockjax](https://github.com/appendto/jquery-mockjax) might be what you looking for.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/u0b0djzy/2/) is your example with some tweaks to get it to output to the div (doesn't work in chrome for me because of the mockjax script mime type)

Html

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<button>Get Data</button>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.mockjax({
        url: '/someurl',
        responseText: [{
            "name": "John Johnson",
            "street": "Oslo West 16",
            "phone": "222 7894562"
            }, 
            {
            "name": "Davie Amber",
            "street": "Alberta 52",
            "phone": "555 1234567"
            }, 
            {
            "name": "Marck William",
            "street": "Delestre 125",
            "phone": "666 7254599"
        }]
    });  

    $("button").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/someurl",
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
                $("#div1").html(JSON.stringify(result));
            }
        });
    });
});
```